# Gridview with columns as rows

Tags: .net, gridview

I have a gridview with the columns as rows.Attached is an image for the gridview I am trying to create.

[image: Gridview Needed]
The 3 Job Class should always appear in the gridview. It should also give the edit access for the date column.
The stored procedure that returns the results always show the job class and the date. It may have less than 3 rows, where it is applicable.

Please let me know how to create this gridview. If gridview is not the correct control, please suggest the control I should be using.

Comment: Please edit your post and provide a sample of the data you're using, and the code to show how you're retrieving it. Without them, it's pretty hard to tell you what you should be using or how you should be using it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want the 3 job classes to be fixed columns and the date values to appear as rows under the job-classes? So it's possible to have n dates for every class?

Comment: The 3 job classes should be fixed. There would be only one date for one job class and it can be edited by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the image you show what you want to do, that's a List... not a Grid.

For such, you can use `<asp:ListView>` control

There are plenty of tutorials out there that will help you to do prety much everything with `ListView`'s, like:

Tutorial

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/CompleteListView.aspx

Video

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgBS289jUEU

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I always show the 3 Job class value in the list view as a row? In my stored procedure, it returns the Job class and date only for the 3 job class, but it may have 2 job class if the 3rd job class is not applicable.